# When exactly does an NSWindow get rounded corners?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

(I found several similar questions, but nothing quite the same.  Some were older than the OS in question.  Some were doing crazy things, like completely custom windows.  Nobody I found has instructions for how to make a perfectly ordinary window work correctly.)

Starting in OS X Lion, standard windows have had rounded corners.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble replicating this in my application.  When an NSView is pushed against the corner of an NSWindow, sometimes it stays clipped to the round NSWindow, and sometimes it escapes and makes a square corner.

I haven't been able to figure out a pattern yet.

- Even NSViews that "draw their background" sometimes force square corners, so it's not that.
- My custom NSViews make square corners (am I responsible for checking my position in the NSWindow, and clipping to that, if I'm near the edge?), but some standard Cocoa controls do this, too.

For example, make a new Cocoa project, put a (scrolling) NSTableView or NSTextView in the main NSWindow, and add layout constraints so it follows the edges of the window.  The bottom corners are square!  The Finder, in contrast, has (what looks like) an NSTableView, right up against the bottom corner of the window, and it's rounded.

How do I make an ordinary NSWindow, with the proper round corners on the bottom?

Comment: My suggestion would be to show the code you've tried, maybe that way someone can help you determine what needs to be done differently.

Comment: There is literally no code.  I described the setup in the last paragraph.  New Cocoa Application, add NSTableView or NSTextView to window, run.

Comment: Generally anything that is outside of default behavior requires code.

Comment: Yes, which is why I'm confused.  Every window in OS X has rounded corners.  Doing the default thing in Xcode gives me square corners.  Why?  Where is the documentation that says how this should work?

Comment: The documentation is that of `NSWindow`, more specifically `NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask`...

Comment: No, NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask was added in 10.2, 9 years before 10.7 started giving windows round corners by default, and its documentation is horribly out of date.  In 10.11, that bit changes the texture, but with or without it, an empty default NSWindow has round corners.

Comment: Who cares when it was added, it's still in the docs - and still works. Also there's more than one way to accomplish rounding a windows corners. It's hard to imagine one of the many examples on this site did not work for you since they seem to work for lots of other folks.

Comment: How is "horribly out of date" documentation *not* a problem?  I confirmed this just now on the latest version of OS X and the latest version of Xcode.  And the other examples on this site involve subclassing NSWindow, which you yourself said should not be necessary for default behavior.  Please, if you can't even reproduce my problem, bully for you, but you're not helping at all.

Comment: This question seems perfectly good to me; upvoted to compensate for the downvote.  I reproduced the problem in about 10 seconds with a new project in Xcode with no code whatsoever, as J. Cocoe said: a textview set right into the corner of the window does indeed make the corner go square, with flawed shadowing no less.  Apple's TextEdit app does not exhibit this problem, so something fishy is going on.  The problem occurs whether the window is set to be textured (i.e. NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask) or not, so that is an irrelevant red herring.

Comment: I'L'I, if you have a link to another SO question that resolves this, please post it.  Your hostility here seems misplaced; at worst this question is a duplicate, but you have not actually demonstrated that it is even that, and your suggested fix has nothing to do with the question.  Please take a deep breath and treat the question fairly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flag to set, in order to get NSWindow to clip its contents to its actual window border (why the heck isn't this the default?) is NSView's `wantsLayer`.

- In code: `contentView!.wantsLayer = true`, when the window is loaded.
- Or in IB: select the root View of your Window, and then in "View Effects inspector", check the box next to it in "Core Animation Layer" (even if you're not using Core Animation).

Meta: the [documentation for `wantsLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW58) talks about a lot of complex things that don't seem at all related to window shape or clipping, and it's not even a property of NSWindow, while NSWindow has some flags that claim to be about window corner rounding but which don't work any more, so I'm not sure how anybody is supposed to discover this, except by spending 2 days on trial-and-error.  I hope this answer helps somebody else!

Comment: This solved my years old problem. Now I can put `NSTextView` at the bottom of a `NSWindow` without worrying about corner rendering...!