# How to get square lower corners in an NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have an `NSWindow` (actually an `NSPanel`, with the "Utility Panel" style set in IB).  In IB it displays as having square lower corners, which is what I want.  When I run my app, however, the window gets rounded lower corners.  That is a problem, because the content I display in this window goes all the way out to the edges of the `contentView`, but the rounded corners clip my content.

I found the opposite question (how to get rounded corners when Cocoa for some reason decides to give you square corners: [When exactly does an NSWindow get rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986010/when-exactly-does-an-nswindow-get-rounded-corners)), but that doesn't shed light on how to solve my problem here.  Specifically, it says that the `wantsLayer` flag on the window's `contentView` governs the squareness/roundness of the window's corners; it says that setting `wantsLayer` to `YES` will give you rounded corners.  That may be true, but I already have rounded corners, and I don't want them.  The `wantsLayer` flag on my window is `NO`, which is the default; I have checked that.  I was hoping that having an opaque subview in the contentView that went right out to the edges of the window would square the corners off, but it does not; my subview is an `NSOpenGLView`, which returns `YES` for `isOpaque`, and the corners are still rounded and clip the contents of the subview.

More broadly, if anybody actually understands how Cocoa decides when to give round corners and when to give square corners, that information would be useful.  Interestingly, I just noticed in Xcode on my machine, the lower right corner of the project window dynamically squares and rounds, depending upon whether the Utilities subpane is visible or not.  Whatever the Utilities subpane does to square off the Xcode window's corner, that's what I want to do.  :->